# Firefox is keeping button in the 'active' state too long

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I am having an issue with Firefox 35. I am using a Thinkpad computer running Windows 7. My issue relates to a page like the one below:

http://jsfiddle.net/garson/fNPvf/11635/

HTML:

```
<body>
<a>testlink.com</a>
<a>testlink2.org</a>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
a:active {
    background-color: #ffff00;
}
```

When I click on the links, they SHOULD briefly flash yellow and return to white background. This works in Chrome. However, in Firefox the links stay yellow until my mouse leaves them.

Anyone know what could be causing this? I have checked and my graphics drivers are all up to date.

Comment: Works same for me in all the browsers :)

Comment: That's so weird. Thanks for letting me know. I don't think my system is that antiquated and can't for the life of me figure out why this is happening.